# Append Object IF Specified to Data Frame: Errors in User Defined Function-R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, dataframe

I'm having trouble trying to get an if else statement to work. Essentially, what I want it to do is as follows: if my object (z) exists then append to my data frame (results <- data.frame(x, y, z)), else do nothing (thus results <- data.frame(x, y)).

Below is a reproducible example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

## Reproducible example

```
library(forecast) 


set.seed(1234)
testData <- rnorm(1000)

mFits <- function(data, mod1, mod2 = NULL, mod3 = NULL) {

  # Must at least choose one model to evaluate
  # If mod2, mod3 are specified in the arguments then evaluate 
  m1 <- mod1(data)$fitted

  if (!is.null(mod2)) {
    m2 <- mod2(data)$fitted
  }

  if (!is.null(mod3)){
    m3 <- mod3(data)$fitted
  }

  # Put fitted values into a data frame

  if (!is.ts(m2)) {
    fits <- data.frame(m1)
  }
  else {
    fits <- data.frame(m1, m2)
  }

  if (!is.ts(m3)) {
    fits <- data.frame(m1)
  }
  else {
    fits <- data.frame(m1, m3)
  }

}

modelFit <- mFits(testData, mod1 = auto.arima, mod2 = NULL, mod3 = NULL)
Error in is.ts(m3) : object 'm3' not found
```

However, I keep getting an error, like the one above. I know m3 does not exists because I did not specify it to exist. Essentially, what I want is a data frame that must have the fitted values from m1, and optionally have the fitted values from m2 and m3 appended if they are specified in the arguments of the function. Could someone point me in the right direction? I'm a bit unsure of what to do next.

Thanks

Comment: Unless the code inside `if (!is.null(mod3)){ }` is executed, m3 doesn't exist; the same for `m2`. Your testing needs to be modified to account for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m3 <- mod3(data)$fitted` only runs if mod3 is not null, right? Here mod3 is null, so it doesn't run. So it's not defined when the code reaches `!is.ts`.

Maybe you mean something like this?

```
m2<-NULL
m3<-NULL
 if (!is.null(mod2)) {
    m2 <- mod2(data)$fitted
  }

  if (!is.null(mod3)){
    m3 <- mod3(data)$fitted
  }
ret <- data.frame(m1)
if(!is.null(m2)) ret <- cbind(ret,m2)
if(!is.null(m3)) ret <- cbind(ret,m3)
return (ret)
```